# I need to export a georeferenced image of a selected layer from OpenLayers application

Tags: openlayers, export, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I need to export a georeferenced image of a selected layer from OpenLayers webgis map application for the extent that the map app is currently showing. The layer in the map is rendered by a WebGLTile Layer and the source data come from Cloud Optimized Geotiff (COG), where some band math is applied and a custom colormap is applied to create the map layer (similar to approach here: https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/cog/ndvi.html).
When I look in the console of the app, it downloads only the portions of the COG it needs for the current view.But these are the data, not rendered images that I could grab. I think the rendering is handled by the WebGLTile.
[image]
Now I need to find a way how to programmatically export it from the map as a georeferenced image (tiff/png/jpg) so I can add it in desktop GIS. Not the whole map composition, only the one raster layer.

EDIT:
I managed to export the PNG of only the selected layer as adviced by @Mike.
However, I need a georeferenced image to serve as a basemap raster layer in QGIS. The image generation must be automated. I cannot do some manual georeferencing of the png.

The code for the export is available here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/export-layer-to-georeferenced-png-forked-j1yfry

Comment: You can export a map as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-map.html  For a single layer set a `className` on the layer and include that in the `querySelectorAll`.  Converting that to a GeoTIFF instead of a PNG could be done by geotiff.js https://github.com/geotiffjs/geotiff.js/#writing-geotiffs-beta-version  The values would be the ImageData of the export canvas.

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: @Mike thank you, that worked. I managed to export PNG, however without any spatial reference. I need to add thisraster layer as a background image layer into QGIS and put some other layers on top of it.